# Finding null values in a json record in a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, null

Let say we have a dataframe with the following format:

```
col1
{'overall_mean': '93.07', 'overall_median': '91.05'}
{}
{'overall_mean': '91.02', 'overall_median': '95.03'}
```

The original data is in json format. I want to extract some elements from each row and here is what I tried:

```
 df['col1'].apply(lambda col: col['overall_mean'])
```

If we have that element in the dictionary, everything is fine but if we don't have, it complains and it make sense. Then I changed to this one:

```
 df['col1'].apply(lambda col: None if len(col['overall_mean']) == 1 else col['overall_mean'])
```

and the reason to choose this conditions `len(col['overall_mean']) == 1` was because that is the only condition that returns `True`. However it still cannot find those null value.

Comment: Maybe this list comprehension will do: `df['col1'].apply(lambda col: col['overall_mean'] if 'overall_mean' in col else None)`

Comment: Would you please add your solution as an answer? get method works faster but your approach is also working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use dictionary's get method ? it will return `None` if the key is not in the dictionary:

```
df.col1.map(lambda x: x.get('overall_mean'))

#0    93.07
#1     None
#2    91.02
#Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Or: `df.col1.apply(lambda x: x.get('overall_mean'))`

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution from @Psidom. Just copying from the comments an alternative one using list comprehensions

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda col: col['overall_mean'] if 'overall_mean' in col else None)
```